# Improve the performance of this windowing-heavy query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql

I have the below code in HQL. It's drawing data from a table with >2.5bn rows and around 334 columns. It takes a while to run so I'm looking for any potential performance boosts where possible. This is main block of the query, there are subsequent CTEs which perform some further processing but the below is the most expensive query.

I appreciate window functions can be heavy in this context, however they are required as highly specific timestamp calculations are needed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
WITH t1 AS ( 
SELECT 
*, 
CASE 
WHEN (LEAD(hour) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`) - hour) > 1 
    THEN NULL 
WHEN (LEAD(hour) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`) - hour) = 1 
    THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`date`, " ", LPAD((hour + 1), 2, 0), ":00:00"), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`date`, " ", REGEXP_REPLACE(`time`, '\\.\\d+', '')), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')   
WHEN (LAG(s_id) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`) = s_id) = TRUE
AND (hour - LAG(hour) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`)) = 1 
AND (LEAD(hour) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`) - hour) = 0 
    THEN (LEAD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`date`, " ", REGEXP_REPLACE(`time`, '\\.\\d+', '')), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`) -  
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`date`, " ", REGEXP_REPLACE(`time`, '\\.\\d+', '')), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') + LAG(hour_overlap_add) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`)) 
ELSE LEAD(unix_timestamp(CONCAT(`date`, " ", regexp_replace(`TIME`, '\\.\\d+', '')), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id, hour ORDER BY `time`) 
- unix_timestamp(CONCAT(`date`, " ", regexp_replace(`TIME`, '\\.\\d+', '')), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') 
END AS time_to_next_trans 
FROM( 
    SELECT 
        *, 
        (overlap_time_to_next_trans - sec_between_current_trans_and_next_hr) as hour_overlap_add 
    FROM( 
        SELECT 
            c_id, 
            s_id, 
            id, 
            rat, 
            dt, 
            `date`, 
            `time`, 
            hour, 
            (LEAD(s_id) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`) = s_id) AS s_id_change, 
            LEAD(hour) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`) - hour AS difference_hour, 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`date`, " ", LPAD((hour + 1), 2, 0), ":00:00"), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') 
            - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`date`, " ", REGEXP_REPLACE(`time`, '\\.\\d+', '')), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS sec_between_current_trans_and_next_hr, 
            LEAD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`DATE`, " ", REGEXP_REPLACE(`TIME`, '\\.\\d+', '')), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`) - 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`DATE`, " ", REGEXP_REPLACE(`TIME`, '\\.\\d+', '')), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS overlap_time_to_next_trans 
        FROM database.tablename
        WHERE dt = "${rundate}” AND ID <> 0 
        )j 
    )o 
)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have most of your derivations in step 1. And then reuse these without deriving again.

```
with j as 
(
  SELECT 
    c_id
    ,s_id
    ,id
    ,rat
    ,dt
    ,`date`
    ,`time`
    ,hour
    ,(LEAD(s_id) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`) = s_id) AS s_id_change_lead
    ,(LAG(s_id) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`) = s_id) AS s_id_change_lag   
    ,LEAD(hour) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`) - hour AS difference_hour
    ,hour - LAG(hour) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`) as new_hour_diff
    ,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`date`, " ", LPAD((hour + 1), 2, 0), ":00:00"), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`date`, " ", REGEXP_REPLACE(`time`, '\\.\\d+', '')), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS sec_between_current_trans_and_next_hr, 
    ,LEAD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`DATE`, " ", REGEXP_REPLACE(`TIME`, '\\.\\d+', '')), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`DATE`, " ", REGEXP_REPLACE(`TIME`, '\\.\\d+', '')), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS overlap_time_to_next_trans 
  FROM database.tablename
  WHERE dt = "${rundate}" AND ID <> 0
),

o as
(
  SELECT 
  *,
  overlap_time_to_next_trans - sec_between_current_trans_and_next_hr as hour_overlap_add
  FROM j
),

t1 as 
(
SELECT 
  *
  ,CASE 
    WHEN difference_hour > 1 
      THEN NULL
    WHEN difference_hour = 1 
      THEN sec_between_current_trans_and_next_hr
    WHEN s_id_change_lag = TRUE AND new_hour_diff=1 AND difference_hour = 0
      THEN overlap_time_to_next_trans + LAG(hour_overlap_add) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY `time`)
    ELSE LEAD(unix_timestamp(CONCAT(`date`, " ", regexp_replace(`TIME`, '\\.\\d+', '')), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id, hour ORDER BY `time`) - unix_timestamp(CONCAT(`date`, " ", regexp_replace(`TIME`, '\\.\\d+', '')), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
  END AS time_to_next_trans
FROM o
)
  
select * from t1;
```

Hope this helps.